# Все работает до определенного момента , код начинает зацикливаться когда я прокручиваю страницу дальше

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 500) {
            $(".slaves")
                .animate({
                    left: '200px',
                    width: '430px'
                }, 1000)
                .animate({ width: '300px' }, 1000)
                .animate({ height: '300px' }, 1000)
                .animate({ width: "300px" });
        }
    });
});
```

После окончания функции предпоследняя анимация зацикливаеться `.animate({ height: '300px' }, 1000)`  .
Не могу разобраться помогите .

Comment: У вас написано, что анимация должна совершаться заново на каждое движение скролла, не отменяя предыдущую анимацию. Вряд ли вы хотели именно такое поведение.

Comment: можешь показать ка это должно выглядеть ?